# Rerendering on Delete button is not working

Tags: visualforce, rerender, commandbutton

I have delete button on page which deletes selected record from page.
The moment I click on button, Record gets deleted but page is not getting refreshed automatically.
To see the changes I need to refresh the page mauanlly.

Below is my Visualforce Page,

```
<apex:page Controller="testPageExt" >
    <apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/versioning.css" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css" />
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('headerSearchContainer')[0].style.display = 'none';
            };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
                var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                  
                    for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){          
                        if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){                                     
                            inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                        }
                    }
                }
        </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Supplier List" helpTitle="supplier" helpUrl="/apex/testPage" >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteSelectedSupplier}" value="Delete Supplier" reRender="supplier"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="List of All Supplier" columns="2" id="PBSection">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!supWrapList}" var="s" id="supplier">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header"><apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputID')"/></apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!s.isSelected}" id="inputID"/>         
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Supplier Name</apex:facet>
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!quoteaction}" value="{!s.supObj.name}" reRender="quote">
                            <apex:param name="sParam" value="{!s.supObj.id}" assignTo="{!supplierValue}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>     
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:pageBlockTable var="r" value="{!quoteList}" id="quote">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quote Name" value="{!r.name}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

*******Controller***********

```
public with sharing class testPageExt {

public List<Quote__c> quoteList {get;set;}
public List<Supplier__c> supllierList {get;set;}
public String supplierValue {get;set;}
public List<wrapSupplier> supWrapList {get;set;}
public List<Supplier__c> selectedSupplier {get;set;}

public testPageExt() {
    supWrapList = new List<wrapSupplier>();
    supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
    system.debug('*********'+supllierList );
    quoteList = null;
    for(supplier__c sObj:supllierList){
        supWrapList.add(new wrapSupplier(sObj));
    }
}

    public pagereference deleteSelectedSupplier(){
        selectedSupplier = new List<Supplier__c>();
        for(wrapSupplier wObj: supWrapList){
            if(wObj.isSelected == True){
                selectedSupplier.add(wObj.supObj);
            }
        }
        Delete selectedSupplier;
        //getSupllieraction();
        return new PageReference ('/apex/testPage');
    }

    public List<Supplier__c> getSupllieraction() {
        supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
        return supllierList ;
    }

    public void quoteaction() {
        quoteList = [Select id, name ,RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c where RFQ_Supplier__c =:supplierValue ];
    }

    public class wrapSupplier {

        public Supplier__c supObj {get;set;}
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}

        public wrapSupplier(supplier__c sObj){

            this.supObj = sObj;
            this.isSelected = False;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try to give the pageBlock an Id and re-render the whole pageBlock rather than just the pageBlockTable

Comment: I made changes but PageBlock is not getting Rerender on button click

Comment: What about if you move it even more up, to the form?

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Didn't get

Comment: Can you post your controller code on how you get the supWrapList, please?

Comment: @LanceShi I have updated my post. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the updated list is because you haven't queried the list after handling the delete. So in your server, the list is not refreshed.

Try updating your code into something like this:

```
public testPageExt() {
    initializeData();
}

public void initializeData()
{
    supWrapList = new List<wrapSupplier>();
    supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
    system.debug('*********'+supllierList );
    quoteList = null;
    for(supplier__c sObj:supllierList){
        supWrapList.add(new wrapSupplier(sObj));
    }
}

    public void deleteSelectedSupplier(){
        selectedSupplier = new List<Supplier__c>();
        for(wrapSupplier wObj: supWrapList){
            if(wObj.isSelected == True){
                selectedSupplier.add(wObj.supObj);
            }
        }
        Delete selectedSupplier;
        initializeData();
    }
```

Comment: I think we are very close to the solution. Anyways It still not working.

Comment: @SfdcPro I updated my code. Try it this time. I updated the return value to void which should be working.

Comment: You are a saviour. It worked. !!! Thanks a Lot. But I didn't  understand how it worked removing pagereference.

Comment: @SfdcPro Well, just remember reRender will not work with returning pageReference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
Note the change below on the pageblock level where i added the id tag:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Supplier List" helpTitle="supplier" helpUrl="/apex/testPage" id="supplier">
```

Complete code -

```
<apex:page Controller="testPageExt" >
    <apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/versioning.css" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css" />
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('headerSearchContainer')[0].style.display = 'none';
            };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
                var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                  
                    for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){          
                        if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){                                     
                            inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                        }
                    }
                }
        </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Supplier List" helpTitle="supplier" helpUrl="/apex/testPage" id="supplier">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteSelectedSupplier}" value="Delete Supplier" reRender="supplier"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="List of All Supplier" columns="2" id="PBSection">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!supWrapList}" var="s" id="supplier">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header"><apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputID')"/></apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!s.isSelected}" id="inputID"/>         
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Supplier Name</apex:facet>
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!quoteaction}" value="{!s.supObj.name}" reRender="quote">
                            <apex:param name="sParam" value="{!s.supObj.id}" assignTo="{!supplierValue}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>     
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:pageBlockTable var="r" value="{!quoteList}" id="quote">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quote Name" value="{!r.name}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**NOTE** - Please also check the browser console that there is no other Javascript error happening in the background.

Comment: I already tried this but not working. Also there is no javascript issues arising on browser.

Comment: Also you made a mistake in your code. You can not give same identical id to more than a single component in visualforce. Same id is given to PageBlock as well PageBlockTable tag in visualforce page

Comment: Ok, didn't notice you already had a pageblock table inside with the same id. How about you name the outer pageblock as id='supplier' and the inner pageblocktable can be id='supplier2'. I remember facing a similar problem but can't remember the fix.

Comment: I tried that also but still not getting refreshed that perticular page block.

Answer (score 0):

Follwing code is the correct answer to my query. 
Many thanks to @Lance Shi

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class testPageExt {

public List<Quote__c> quoteList {get;set;}
public List<Supplier__c> supllierList {get;set;}
public String supplierValue {get;set;}
public List<wrapSupplier> supWrapList {get;set;}
public List<Supplier__c> selectedSupplier {get;set;}

public testPageExt() {
    initializeData();
}

    public void initializeData()
    {
        supWrapList = new List<wrapSupplier>();
        supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
        system.debug('*********'+supllierList );
        quoteList = null;
        for(supplier__c sObj:supllierList){
            supWrapList.add(new wrapSupplier(sObj));
        }
    }

    public void deleteSelectedSupplier(){
        selectedSupplier = new List<Supplier__c>();
        for(wrapSupplier wObj: supWrapList){
            if(wObj.isSelected == True){
                selectedSupplier.add(wObj.supObj);
            }
        }
        Delete selectedSupplier;
        initializeData();

    }

    public List<Supplier__c> getSupllieraction() {
        supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
        return supllierList ;
    }

    public void quoteaction() {
        quoteList = [Select id, name ,RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c where RFQ_Supplier__c =:supplierValue ];
    }

        public class wrapSupplier {

        public Supplier__c supObj {get;set;}
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}

        public wrapSupplier(supplier__c sObj){

            this.supObj = sObj;
            this.isSelected = False;
        }
    } 
}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="testPageExt" >
<apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/versioning.css" />
<apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css" />
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('headerSearchContainer')[0].style.display = 'none';
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
            var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                  
                for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){          
                    if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){                                     
                        inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Supplier List" helpTitle="supplier" helpUrl="/apex/testPage" id="PGB">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteSelectedSupplier}" value="Delete Supplier" reRender="PGB"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="List of All Supplier" columns="2" id="PBSection">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!supWrapList}" var="s" id="supplier">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header"><apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputID')"/></apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!s.isSelected}" id="inputID"/>         
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Supplier Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!quoteaction}" value="{!s.supObj.name}" reRender="quote">
                        <apex:param name="sParam" value="{!s.supObj.id}" assignTo="{!supplierValue}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>     
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="r" value="{!quoteList}" id="quote">
                <apex:column headerValue="Quote Name" value="{!r.name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```